# JSF command button redirect url does not open in the same frame

Tags: jsf

I have a  in my form which redirects to another page in a 3rd party product.The action event of the button is given below:

```
 public void returnToTrackerSummary() throws IOException {        
        StringBuilder trackerSummaryURL = new StringBuilder();   
        trackerSummaryURL.append(PropsUtil.getProperty(PropsDef.a));         

         FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().redirect(trackerSummaryURL.toString());    


    }
```

My issue is on clicking the button it goes to the new page but the header gets painted twice.Added the url of the redirect page is not updated. Though the latter is not a big issue,I really want the page to open in the same frame as in with one header.Any ideas?

Comment: h:commandbutton in my form

Comment: why not a simple href?

Comment: would you mind posting your xhtml(s)?